# import csv or text file to database

Tags: database, postgresql, jakarta-ee

i want to export datas in csv file(csv file is a type as the excel file) or text file to my database, in other hand the csv file contains columns that are the seem one in the database except same of them.
I work under a Java EE platform with struts, spring and hibernate frameworks, and postgereSQL as database.

Comment: don't you mean CSV file?

Comment: Attempting to translate... "I want to programatically import data from a CSV file to a database table. The CSV file contains some columns that do not exist in the table. I work under a Java EE platform with Struts, Spring and Hibernate frameworks, and use PostgreSQL as a database."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize postgresql's [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) command